# Trying to remove the Windows 10 Technical Preview but Windows Update KB2990214 does not exist on my computer

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

I'm trying to get rid of the Windows 10 Tech Preview because it's screwing up some of my computer games. I've seen solutions online that include removing windows update KB2990214, but after checking I've realized that KB2990214 does not exist on my computer.

My previous operating system was Windows 8.1, and I have the installation disc.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you installed Win10 right on top of/on the same disk partition as your previous Win8 installation?

That was not wise.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq?ocid=tp_site_faqpage#faq=tab0

What Windows is basically saying, is that you shouldn't install Win10 on a computer that you aren't prepared to nuke in situations like these which brings me to the actual answer to the question: that there is no really great way to get rid of it if you installed it on the same partition as your previous install. The Technical Preview is unfortunately not an update, but an honest-to-god operating system and the only way to go back to Win8 is to use those installation disks and reformat your entire HDD.

I installed it on my laptop on a separate partition from my main Win7 OS so even if it breaks or otherwise becomes unusable, all I have to do is nuke that little 50GB partition and start over. It's like Windows' own little padded cell.

Comment: Oh Lord. I knew I should have read the instructions. Yes, I did install Win10 op top of the same disc partition. Well, I'd rather not reformat the entire HDD so I'll stick with Win10 for the time being. If worse comes to worse, I'll back up my important documents and format. Thanks for the information.